# NameError: uninitialized constant LoremIpsum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have a FActory using the factory_girl_rails gem 3.2

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:random_string) {|n| "#{LoremIpsum.generate}#{n}" }
  factory :agenda do
    subject { generate(:random_string) }
    due_date "2012-05-14"
    completed false
    user
  end
end
```

but I'm getting a NoNameError in my Rspec tests.
I've googled and looked at the FactoryGirl docs and my code seems correct.

FYI, I'm calling 
FactoryGirl.create(:agenda, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago) in my tests that is causing throwing the error.

I'm just trying to have random test generator for my Factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using lorem-ipsum gem make sure it is in your gemfile for test environment

```
gem "lorem-ipsum", :group=>:test
```

Comment: Now I receive  NoMethodError undefined method 'generate' for  LoremIpsum:Module

Comment: Solved it. Gonna use Faker. Thanks for the lore-ipsum gem

Comment: For future visitors, it's now: ````LoremIpsum::Generator.new.generate({words: 1})````